# npm install code ENOENT & syscall rename issue

Tags: node.js, npm

Salutations!
I'm frustrated.
I did the following like I've done a hundred times on my previous laptop:

```
npm init
npm i express
```

Normally everything's fine but... now I'm getting this while the package is installing:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Thanos\Express Server\node_modules\cookie-signature
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Thanos\Express Server\node_modules\.cookie-signature.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Thanos\Express Server\node_modules\cookie-signature' -> 'C:\Users\Thanos\Express Server\node_modules\.cookie-signature.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have:

- Already installed git
- npm cache clean (which doesn't work with this latest version on npm)
- reinstalled node (also included chocolatey) & restarted
- remade the relevant AppData folder

$ npm --version 6.14.11

$ node --version v14.15.5

Windows 10

Comment: Can you post your code snippet? What OS/version are you using? Also, can you explain when the error happens? On installing express or renaming a folder from your code. A litle bit further explanation explaintion would be great. Have you tried to delete `node_modules`?

Comment: Updated. No code, just an empty index.js

Comment: Please don't put "SOLVED" in the title. Accept an answer which provides a solution and Stack Overflow will automatically flag this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My folder was located inside Dropbox. A Dropbox process is preventing the package installation. When I created the folder locally everything worked as expected.

If you want to keep your files in Dropbox you can simply pause syncing.

Comment: Oh my GOD!!!
I've been suffering with this for almost a full year now!!
Everytime I create a new project I spend hours going through everyone's suggesstions online, and then debugging by going through log and manually replacing files one by one and then deleting and re-installing and clearing cache, and trying again, until everytime by sheer luck it somehow works after hours wasted trying random crap!!!
Now I understand why!!
%&^*ing DROPBOX!!!!!
I just created a package outside of Dropbox folder and it worked flawlessy!!
THANK YOU!!